# Gauss Lemma - Do Carmo's Riemannian geometry, use of parallel transport?

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I was exactly having the same doubt as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175727/proof-of-gausss-lemma-riemannian-geometry-version). I don't understand specifically why

$$
(d \exp_p)_v(v)=v
$$

I worked out exactly the same math as wikipedia and I ended up with

$$
(d \exp_p)_v(v) = \frac{d}{dt}\left. \left(\gamma((t+1),p,v) \right) \right|_{t=0}
$$

The equation is based on the use of the curve $\alpha(t) = (t+1)v$ where $v \in T_p M$. Apparently the key in understanding how to fill the gap is to use somehow the parallel transport but I couldn't figure from the given answer actually.

The specific bit I can't figure is that apparently, from one of the comments, it might be the case that the result of $(d \exp_p)_v(v)$ is actually the parallel transport of $v$ along the geodesic passing through $\exp_p(v)$.

Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be easier than you think if you stick to do Carmo's text. The key claim is that
$$
\langle d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(w_T) \rangle = \langle v,w_T \rangle,
$$
for any $w_T = av \in T_pM$.  By the fact that $\gamma(t) = \text{exp}_p(tv)$, we can compute $d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v)$ by taking $v$ as the initial velocity of the curve $\alpha(t) = v+vt$ starting at $v$. We will obtain $d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v) = \gamma'(1)$. So we have
\begin{align}
\langle d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(w_T) \rangle &= a \, \langle d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v) \rangle \\ 
&=a \, \langle \gamma'(1),\gamma'(1) \rangle \\ 
&= a\, \langle \gamma'(0),\gamma'(0) \rangle\\
&= a\,  \langle v,v \rangle\\
&= \langle v,w_T \rangle,
\end{align}
where the third equality holds because $\langle \gamma'(t),\gamma'(t) \rangle$ is constant along geodesic $\gamma$.

Comment: The only property of the exponential map metioned is $(d \exp_p)_o(v) = v$ So I'm not sure which properties you're using to show $\gamma'(1) = (d \exp_p)_v(v)$. I'm also not sure about the chain of equalities your wrote. Specifically $$a \, \langle d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v) \rangle =\langle \gamma'(1),\gamma'(1) \rangle = a\, \langle \gamma'(0),\gamma'(0) \rangle $$

Comment: @user8469759 Refering to your equalities on the comment : We just use linearity of exponential map to pull out $a$ from the inner product. The first equality is from $\gamma'(1) = d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v)$. The second is from $\langle \gamma' ,\gamma' \rangle$ is constant.

Comment: For the second equality $$\langle \gamma'(1),\gamma'(1) \rangle = a\, \langle \gamma'(0),\gamma'(0) \rangle$$ didn't you forget the fact $a$ then? And for the first should you start from $$\langle d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(av) \rangle= a \, \langle d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v) \rangle$$ then? I'd still like to know about the parallel transport however, because wikipedia uses this in his proof.

Comment: @user8469759 To get $\gamma'(1)=d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v)$, we consider reparametrization $\gamma(1+t) = \text{exp}_p(v(1+t))$. Take derivative of this curve at $t=0$.

Comment: Ok so I think I see what's happening. We have $$\langle d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(w_T) \rangle= \langle d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(av) \rangle= \langle d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(av) \rangle = a \langle d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v) \rangle$$ by both definition of $w_T$ and linearity of differentials. By definition of exponential map we have $$a \langle d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v) \rangle = a \langle \gamma'(1), \gamma'(1) \rangle $$

Comment: And by parallel transport, which follows from the definition of geodesic as mentioned by @chris we have $$a \langle \gamma'(1), \gamma'(1) \rangle  = a \langle \gamma'(0), \gamma'(0) \rangle$$ all the rest is straight forward from properties of inner product. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to answer, or at least to prove part of Gauss's lemma without needing to claim that $d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v) = v$. This equation makes me a little worried because $v \in T_p M$, whereas $d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v) \in T_{\text{exp}_p(v)}M$ and so a priori equating them doesn't make sense. What I assume is happening is that they are abusing notation and writing this equation for the shorthand of "$d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v)$ is the parallel transport along $\text{exp}_p(tv)$ of $v$". Another answer talking more about this to correct me/shed some more light on this would be wonderful, especially if this isn't the case.

Like you wrote, we want to evaluate this derivative by writing it as the time derivative, evaluated at a certain time, of a path which at that time is $v$ and has derivative $v$. It's convenient to write it as follows:
$$
d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t = 1} \text{exp}_p(t v).
$$
Note that $t \mapsto tv$ is $v$ at $t = 1$ and has time derivative $v$ everywhere. But $\gamma : t \mapsto \text{exp}_p(tv)$ is the geodesic starting at $p$ which has initial velocity $v$. If we define $V(t)$ to be the velocity vector field along $\gamma$ then we know that $\nabla_{V}V = 0$. Then $d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v)$ is the velocity vector of $\gamma$ at $t = 1$, and we have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}g(V(t), V(t)) = 2g(\nabla_V V, V) = 0
$$
since $V$ is parallel transported along $\gamma$. This proves that $g(d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v)) = (v, v)$. I believe that this is all you need to prove Gauss's lemma, because I think you just decompose the claim $g(d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v), d(\text{exp}_p)_v(w))$ into the cases when $w = \lambda v$ (in which case we proved it above) and $w$ is orthogonal to $v$ (in which case I don't think (?) you need the assertion about the equality of $d(\text{exp}_p)_v(v)$ and $v$).

Comment: Why is in your answer $\nabla_V V = 0$?.

Comment: Because $V$ is the velocity vector of $\gamma$, which is a geodesic, and geodesics have the property that their velocity is parallel transported along the curve itself. I probably should have just written $V(t) = \dot \gamma(t)$, so then the equation is $\nabla_{\dot \gamma}\dot \gamma = 0$.

Comment: your last comment. do Carmo defines a curve $\gamma : I \subset \mathbb{R} \to M$ to be *geodesic at $t_0 \in I$* if $$ \frac{D}{dt} \left( \frac{d\gamma}{dt} \right) = 0$$. I guess your statement follows from this definition then, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I don't remember how exactly do Carmo does it, but $(D/dt)\dot \gamma(t) = \nabla_{\dot \gamma(t)}\dot \gamma(t)$. The trouble/nuance is that $\dot\gamma(t)$ is only a vector field defined along the curve $\gamma$, not on the manifold $M$, so some care is required to interpret what the right-hand side means. However the value of $\nabla_{\dot\gamma(t)}V$ depends only on the value of $V$ along the curve $\gamma$, so one can check the right hand side is well-defined.

Comment: To be honest these are the sort of observation the author should make... It completely slipped my mind that $$\frac{D}{dt} \left( \frac{d\gamma}{dt} \right) = 0$$ was the parallel transport definition almost, he could have defined the geodesic in terms of parallel transport already.